# How to catch message size too big exception when sending emails using System.Net.Mail?

Tags: c#, exception, smtpclient, system.net.mail

I am using System.Net.Mail library to send emails in C#. I want to somehow check the case that a message was not sent, because it was too big. This is a sample code I wrote to illustrate the problem:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        var client = new SmtpClient();
        try
        {
            var mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.From = new MailAddress("sender@mail.com");
            mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("recipient@mail.com"));
            mail.Subject = "Mail Subject";
            mail.Body = "Mail Body";
            mail.Attachments.Add(CreateAttachment());
            var smtpClient = new SmtpClient("SomeHost", 25)
            {
                EnableSsl = false,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password"),
            };
            smtpClient.Send(mail);
        }
        catch (SmtpException e)
        {
            // somehow verify that this exception happened because exceeding message size
            Console.WriteLine("Message was not sent because it was to big"); ;
        }
    }

    // This method generates an attachment that exceed maximum size allowed by the server
    private static Attachment CreateAttachment()
    {
        var str = "Some message\n";
        var superBigMessage = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
        {
            superBigMessage.Append(str);
        }
        return Attachment.CreateAttachmentFromString(superBigMessage.ToString(), "Attachment.txt");
    }
}
```

I would like to mention that there is a property on `SmtpException` called `StatusCode` but it doesn't provide the necessary insight in case the message is too big `StatusCode = TransactionFailed` and the exception message says `Transaction failed. The server response was: Rejected - Message size exceeds fixed maximum message size. Size: 147442 KB, Max size: 20480 KB`

Comment: @mjwills It's hard to validate the exact message size, because the message will probably get encoded during the sending and some additional information will probably be sent along the way, so I doubt I can calculate the message size accurately.

Comment: Could you check a lower limit (e.g. 18MB) to give yourself a bit of a buffer?

Comment: @mjwills I guess, but that's probably not a very good solution, I may end up not sending a message even when it can be sent.

Comment: @mjwills I'm sending a csv report as an attachment to the email, it may grow quite big, so I wanna create some safety mechanism that will prevent big messages from sending. I'm also zipping this file yet it does not guarantee it will be small enough.

Comment: The CSV is > 20 MB **after zipping**?

Comment: @mjwills not a common case, but could be

Comment: I am having the same problem and my client wants to know why the mail was not sent? Can we get the status code in exception for something like "attachment size too big"?

Answer (score 2):

How your MTA treats "too big" and how it reports it is up to that MTA. A different MTA may have a completely different message. There is nothing in `SMTP` that standardises "too big".

Therefore you need to parse the message, and be prepared to update if the MTA changes (including software upgrades and configuration changes).